# WordPress folder ownership issues

Tags: permissions

Hi I set up wordpress on a VPS and I'm running into two problems:

1. Either WordPress asks for ftp details in order to update plugins or delete them

or

1. Through FTP I cannot delete files as I get a permission denied error.

Problem 1 is solved by running:
sudo chown -R www-data public_html

Problem 2 is solved by running:
sudo chown -R myusername public_html

Solving one problem creates the other apparently. I want to be able to login with my user to ftp and modify anything, while I also want wordpress to be able to update plugins and such things. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run something like

`sudo chown -R myusername:www-data public_html`

it will solve both the problems together

Comment: I tried that and it seemed to work, however now I am being asked for ftp details again when I try to install a plugin.

Comment: ok then try this 'sudo chown -R www-data:myusername public_html' see it it works.

Answer (score 1):

`chown www-data:www-data public_html/ -R`

On Ubuntu and Debian apache & php run as the www-data user and www-data group so any files that php needs to be able to write to have to be owned by the user and group.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the sticky bit on your permissions